# Assert statement returns False even though the returned string seems to be identical to the asserting one

Tags: python, assertion

The class below allows to create and edit a text object has three methods - `write()` adds new text to the existing one, `set_font` adds name of the new font in square brackets to the beginning and the end of the text, and `show()` simply prints the text:

```
import re

class Text:
    def __init__(self):
        self.content = ''

    def write(self, text):
        match = re.search(r'\[[^\]]*\]$', self.content, re.IGNORECASE)
        if match:
            font_name = match.group(0)
            self.content = font_name + self.content.replace(font_name, '') + text + font_name
        else:
            self.content += text

    def set_font(self, font_name):
        new_font = "[{}]".format(font_name)
        match = re.match(r'\[[^\]]*\]', self.content, re.IGNORECASE)
        if match:
          old_font = match.group(0)
          self.content = self.content.replace(old_font, new_font)
        else:
          self.content = new_font + self.content + new_font

    def show(self):
        print(self.content)
```

When I create and manipulate the object in the code below it seems to work as it's supposed to but it doesn't pass the assertion-test below even thought it seems to output the identical result string to the one in the `assert` statement.
Can you help me see what I'm missing?

```
    text = Text()

    text.write("At the very beginning ")
    text.set_font("Arial")
    text.write("there was nothing.")

    assert text.show() == "[Arial]At the very beginning there was nothing.[Arial]"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

text.show does not return a value, it just prints the result.

The Python function will return None, and then compare None to the required string, resulting in False.

Comment: This is it! Thanks